# Adding Date variable

Tags: shell

I want to add the code below to my script but it's not showing the `total_time` value although `CurrentTime` is showing correctly. In this I want to change epoch time to current system time and then add 20 minutes to it.

```
CurrentTime=`date -d @$2`
echo "CurrentTime : $CurrentTime " >> ${LOGFILE}
Total_time=`"$CurrentTime" -d "+20 min"`
```

How can I do it?

Comment: have you tried with date -d="+20 minutes"?

Answer (score 0):

Change your totaltime assignment like this:

```
Total_time=`date -d "$CurrentTime +20 mins"`
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working is that by the time you're trying to assign the value to `$Total_time`, your `$CurrentTime` variable has already been set to a time.  It's not a command anymore, it's a string that is the result of a command.

Each time you want to calculate a new date, you need a new invocation of the `` `date` `` command.  That's what Guru's answer provides you with, though he didn't explain why.

If what you need is to make a "base" date to which you apply modifiers, you can still do this, but I'd recommend a slightly different notation:

```
#!/bin/bash

start=$(date '+%s')

# do stuff
sleep 20

duration=$((`date '+%s'` - $start))
```

You can then use your `$duration` as an easier basis for other calculations, *AND* you can use it with relative dates:

```
printf "[%s] Start of job\n" "$(date -d @$start '+%Y-%m-%d %T')"
...
printf "[%s] End of job\n" "$(date -d @"$((start + duration))" '+%Y-%m-%d %T')"
```

Probably better to format your log files in a more standard format than `date`'s default.